# Minimal error chebyshev interpolation

Tags: analysis, interpolation, chebyshev-polynomials

Let's say the n-degree Chebyshev polynomials :

$$ T_{n} (x)=\cos(n\arccos(x))$$

Make a polynomial such that:

$$\mid y- P (x) \mid$$

be minimal, using the first three Chebyshev polynomials for the following data:

\begin{bmatrix}
x & -1 & -0.5 & 0 & 0.5 & 1 \\
y & 0.6346 & 0.6565 & 1 & 1.5230 & 1.5756 
\end{bmatrix}

How could we manage to approach such a problem?

Comment: Your error criterion is not clearly stated by $|y-P(x)|$.  What is $y$?  Generally one is not interested in minimizing the difference at a single point.  One might be interested in a problem that involves several points, but $|y-P(x)|$ doesn't clearly relate to an error at more than one point.  Various objective functions can be minimized, e.g.. the least squares error, the sum of absolute errors, the maximum of absolute errors, and there are specialized algorithms for these depending on whether the error is measure over a discrete set of points or over intervals.

Comment: I just want to create a polynomial with chabyshev's interpolation to satisfy the table below. About the error i mean the error in those 5 points we need to be minimal
* Y = F (X)

Comment: Also what is $\|\cdot \|$? Often one of the most interesting questions is how to measure the error.

Comment: I mean the absolute value of this subtraction needs to be minimal. In other words i need a polynomial that goes through all those point as close as possible.

Comment: Ok so it is the sum of the $|y-P(x) |$ or the product or something else? Since you have several different pairs of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: We want the minimal error for every point individually not the sum. Using only the three first Chebyshev polynomials always.

Comment: Yes but you must define some cost function for the whole problem if you want to minimize something. You cannot just have 5 separate cost functions with no connection to each other.

Comment: For example you can choose $|y_1-P(x_1)| + |y_2-P(x_2)| + \cdots +|y_5 - P(x_5)|$ because it will become one real number which you can try to make minimal.

Comment: I was about to say the same thing. Yeah that will work also. I saw this exercise in an old book so i dont have the luxury of asking questions to the writer.

Comment: To *interpolate* these five points (with equally spaced arguments on $[-1,+1]$) means to have zero error at each point.  We can do that with a linear combination of the first five Chebyshev polynomials in a unique way.  If you have the "old book", you might review it to see if it means to interpolate (match exactly) the five points.